# After upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, bumblebee doesn't work anymore

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, switchable-graphics

When I try to "optirun steam", for instance, I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/env: error while loading shared libraries: libturbojpeg.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to solve this problem so that I can use my good video card to run programs again?

Thanks for your help,
Erik.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a solution, if you check:

> http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html

You'll see that the filename has changed from libturbojpeg.so to libturbojpeg.so.0 which breaks bumblebee. Follow the instructions there to fix it.

Comment: Why don't you post the one-liner that fixes it so that the information here stays valid even if the link you refer to should be lost?